# object github is not a member of package com

Tags: scala, playframework

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

build.sbt

```
name := """sample"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"        % "2.2.+",
  "com.h2database"  %  "h2"                 % "1.4.+",
  "ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"    % "1.1.+",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth"      % "0.13.2",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth-test" % "0.13.2" % "test",
  "com.github.t3hnar" %% "scala-bcrypt" % "2.4"
)
```

アプリケーションを起動できませんどうしたらよいですか？

Comment: build.sbt に `"com.github.t3hnar" %% "scala-bcrypt" % "2.4"` の行を追加した後に、sbt( activator )を reload してない、とかでしょうか？

Comment: そのとおりでした。。。ありがとうございました

Comment: @KoyaFukushi 蛇足ではございますが、「コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理」 → http://goo.gl/giYtg7

Comment: なるほど。こういうことであってますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> build.sbt に "com.github.t3hnar" %% "scala-bcrypt" % "2.4" の行を追加した後に、sbt( activator )を reload してない、とかでしょうか？ –  Kenji Yoshida 3月31日 2:14